# Non-regular Connected Hausdorff Banach Manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, banach-manifold, manifolds, reference-request

After reading [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/104575/under-exactly-what-extra-conditions-if-any-is-a-connected-hausdorff-manifold), I am wondering:

**Is every (connected) Hausdorff Banach manifold a regular space?**

Though unjustified, page 53 of [this paper](http://www.maik.ru/full/rusmath/97/10/rusmath10_97p49full.pdf) nonchalantly states: "Note that a Hausdorff Banach manifold X is a regular space."

But does anyone know of a proof of this statement (or a counterexample)?

Of course, the real difficulty arises in proving the statement for the infinite-dimensional version, since such a Banach manifold will *not* be locally compact.

---

**Follow-up:** Now that Theo Buehler has kindly pointed to a counterexample (i.e. a connected Hausdorff Banach manifold which is *not* regular) perhaps it will give someone an idea about how to tackle [the question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/104575/under-exactly-what-extra-conditions-if-any-is-a-connected-hausdorff-manifold) that provided the inspiration for this one.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Apparently the answer is **no**, not every connected Hausdorff Banach manifold is regular, not even when it is modeled on a separable Hilbert space.

I quote (verbatim) from J. Margalef-Roig, E. Outerelo-Dominguez, *Differential Topology*, North Holland Mathematics Studies 173, 1992, page 44f.

> It is well known the result of General Topology that every
>   Hausdorff locally compact topological space satisfies the
>   Tychonoff axiom [M-O-P, V.2, pg. 231]. By this and the Riesz's
>   theorem every Hausdorff locally finite dimensional differentiable
>   manifold satisfies the Tychonoff axiom. This last affirmation is not
>   true for arbitrary Hausdorff differentiable manifolds. In
>   [M.O.1] there is an example of a Hausdorff connected
>   differentiable manifold $X$ of class $\infty$, such that $\partial X = \emptyset$,  $X$ is not
>   regular and $X$ admits an atlas whose charts are modelled over an
>   infinite dimensional separable real Hilbert space.

They continue to add the regularity hypothesis in their results whenever it is needed.

The cited references are:

- [M.O.P.] MARGALEF, J.-OUTERELO, E.-PINILLA, J.L.: Topologia,
  I-V. Alhambra, Madrid 1975, 79, 79, 80 and 1982.
- [M.O.1] MARGALEF, J.-OUTERELO, E.: Una variedad diferenciable
  de dimension infinita, separada y no regular.
  Rev. Mat. Hisp.-Am, IV, V.42, 1982, 51-55. [(QuickView link)](http://tinyurl.com/8kb3m45).

---

**Edit:** As was pointed out by Benjamin Dickman in the comments, the example also appears in English in A. Kriegl, P.W. Michor, *[The convenient setting of global analysis](http://books.google.com/books?id=s7fPYRqhXEUC)*, AMS (1997), [**27.6** Non-regular manifold](http://books.google.com/books?id=s7fPYRqhXEUC&pg=PA266), page 266. The book is available as [a pdf file](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~kriegl/Skripten/apbook.pdf) on Kriegl's homepage.

Comment: A Google search for the title of the relevant paper gives various hits, so the paper appears to be online, but, unfortunately, none of the links seems to work right now.

Comment: Thanks for these additional pointers, I incorporated them into the answer.